# Cannot restore session despite box being checked?

Tags: notepad++, session-restore

[image: An image of "Remember current session for next launch" in the toggled state.]

All of the sudden, NPP has stopped remembering my sessions.  It's already frustrating enough that sessions are not remembered between versions, now they are not even remembered between restarts.  I am wondering if this may have been the result of unplugging the drive that had the custom backup location and re-plugging it with the same driver letter several days later.

My plan is to try to re-install NPP and possibly reproduce the bug.  If anyone else has some experience with this problem, please let me know if you have taken steps to resolve it without re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

- I would suggest that you look at `session.xml` file in your Notepad++ installation folder. Does it have any traces of previously saved session file lists? (Make sure that you close Notepad++ and open the session.xml in notepad or any other text editor.) Here is how my `session.xml` file look like.

[image: session file in Notepad++]

- You can also check the `config.xml` file in Notepad (Again make sure that the Notepad++ is closed). There is an xml entry as shown below:

  ```
  <GUIConfig name="RememberLastSession">yes</GUIConfig>
  ```

Is it set to `Yes`? (**Note**: please be careful viewing/editing `config.xml` file. If you do not have lots of customizations in Notepad++ settings, it should be ok. But, if you do, I would make a backup of `config.xml` file before viewing/checking them.)

You can even delete `session.xml` file and restart Notepad++. I changed my `session.xml` file (intentionally messed it up). But after Notepad++ restart, it was able to restore and `Remember Last Session` feature worked fine in the next sessions of Notepad++.

If nothing above works, then you can uninstall and reinstall Notepad++.

(on a side note, you can also test [Save Session and Load Session from File Menu](https://youtu.be/hn_g7vaeHME) to check if that works.

(*Disclaimer: The linked video is from my YouTube channel, which demonstrates save and load sessions in Notepad++.*)

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can make changed to a file in your Notepad++ installation directory.

I know that my employer has locked down my workstation and I can only make changes in my installation directory in Administrator mode, so when running Notepad++ in normal mode, I lose my session every time, including the list of recently opened files, an macros saved, custom keyboard shortcuts, etc.